# What is the proper way to access python class variables?

Tags: python, class-variables

Having a class

```
class A(object):
    z = 0

    def Func1(self):
        return self.z

    def Func2(self):
        return A.z
```

Both methods (`Func1` and `Func2`) give the same result and are only included in this artificial example to illustrate the two possible methods of how to address `z`.

The result of `Func*` would only differ if an instance would shadow `z` with something like `self.z = None`.

What is the proper python way to access the class variable `z` using the syntax of `Func1` or `Func2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the proper way to get access to the variable is simply:

```
a_instance.z  #instance variable 'z'
A.z           #class variable 'z'
```

No need for `Func1` and `Func2` here.

---

As a side note, if you *must* write `Func2`, it seems like a `classmethod` might be appropriate:

```
@classmethod
def Func2(cls):
    return cls.z
```

---

As a final note, which version you use within methods (`self.z` vs. `A.z` vs. `cls.z` with `classmethod`) really depends on how you want your API to behave.  Do you want the user to be able to shadow `A.z` by setting an instance attribute `z`?  If so, then use `self.z`.  If you don't want that shadowing, you can use `A.z`.  Does the method need `self`?  If not, then it's probably a classmethod, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only included `Func1` and `Func2` as an example on how to address `z`. I like your idea of _how the API should behave_. So I guess that this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually use `self.z`, because in case there are subclasses with different values for `z` it will choose the "right" one. The only reason not to do that is if you know you will always want the `A` version notwithstanding.

Accessing via self or via a classmethod (see mgilson's answer) also facilitates the creating of mixin classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about value clobbering and things like that, you're fine with `self.z`.  Otherwise, `A.z` will undoubtedly evaluate to the class variable.  Beware, though, about what would happen if a subclass `B` redefines `z` but **not** `Func2`:

```
class B(A):
    z = 7

b = B()
b.Func2()  # Returns 0, not 7
```

Which is quite logical, after all.  So, if you want to access a class variable in a, somehow, *polymorphic* way, you can just do one of the following:

```
self.__class__.z
type(self).z
```

[According to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), the second form does not work with old-style classes, so the first form is usually more comptaible across Python 2.x versions.  However, the second form is the safest one for new-style classes and, thus, for Python 3.x, as classes may redefine the `__class__` attribute.